# Search specific word and move pdf

Tags: python, shutil, pypdf

I am creating an search engine that is looking for a specific word in pdf, and if it finds it it will move folder to different folder.

This is what I have done so far!

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import os    
import shutil  

pattern = input("Enter string pattern to search: ")

src = 'Folder 1'
dest = 'Folder 2'

for file_name in os.listdir(src):
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_name, 'rb')
    numPages = object.getNumPages()

    for i in range(0, numPages):
        pageObj = object.getPage(i)
        text = pageObj.extractText()
   
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
            print(f'Page no: {i} | Match: {match}')
            destination = shutil.copytree(src, dest, copy_function = shutil.copy)
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I think the error is in following line because it does not see path, but only the name  of the file in folder.

```
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_name, 'rb')
```

How to assign path before file_name?

Comment: I would believe this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` would also show the line number along with the error.

Comment: line 20, in <module>
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_name, 'rb')

Comment: I just need to put src before file_name somehow

Comment: try building the complete path using pathlib

Comment: object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(os.path.join(src, file_name), 'rb')

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pathlib import Path                                           # change
import PyPDF2
import re
import os    
import shutil  

pattern = input("Enter string pattern to search: ")

basepath = Path('') # absolute path to parent of folder 1/folder 2 # change

src = basepath / 'Folder 1'                                        # change
dest = basepath / 'Folder 2'                                       # change

for file in os.scandir(src):                                  # change
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(str(src / file.name), 'rb')      # change
    numPages = object.getNumPages()

    for i in range(0, numPages):
        pageObj = object.getPage(i)
        text = pageObj.extractText()
        mvFlag = True
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
            print(f'Page no: {i} | Match: {match}')                # change below 
            if len(match)!=0 and mvFlag == True:
                destination = shutil.copytree(str(src / file.name), str(dest / file.name), copy_function = shutil.copy)
                mvFlag = False        # because we will move one pdf only once
```

Comment: Now I am getting a logical error. When condition is meet and and code gets to ```estination = shutil.copytree(str(src), str(dest), copy_function = shutil.copy)``` it moves every file in folder. What makes sense because I am using str(src) what leads to whole folder. Do you know how to explain to code to take only that specific file and move it to Folder 2?

Comment: place a check condition on match and instead of passing src and dest, pass paths of files concerned

Comment: This is literally first time that I am doing anything like it. Could you please show me with an example.